# Populate Dropdown from SQL in Classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic, drop-down-menu

I am trying to force users to only select certain values when adding a record.  So naturally I am using a dropdown, but I'd like the options to be populated by a specific field in the database.  I figured I'd do a Do/Loop but I am apparently doing something wrong.

```
Dim dstrSQL
Dim drs
    dstrSQL = "SELECT EventID FROM Events"
    set conn2 = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    conn2.open CONN_STRING
    set drs = conn2.execute(dstrSQL)
    conn2.close: set conn2 = nothing
Do
        Response.Write "<option value=" & drs.Fields(0) & " >" & drs.Fields(0) & "</option>"
        drs.MoveNext
Loop
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's been a long time.  Something like this:

```
conn2.open CONN_STRING
set drs = conn2.execute(dstrSQL)

do while not drs.eof %>

    <option value="<%= drs.Fields(0) %>" ><%= drs.Fields(0) %></option>
    <% drs.MoveNext
Loop
 conn2.close
 set conn2 = nothing %>
```

Comment: Awesome, super fast!  Thanks a bunch =)

Comment: I seem to recall needing to use the .Value property of the Field as well, so you'd have drs.Fields(0).Value inside the loop.  Could be wrong though...

Comment: Maybe .Value is the default property so it's optional.

Comment: if drs is a ADODB Recordset object you can also use drs("EventID")

Comment: Jon P, I was going to say something similar.  I prefer the named columns as they are easier to remember what they mean.

Comment: I want to edit that code to put an open <% tag at the start of it, but its only 2 characters so I can't make the change.  Granted it should be understood that you need to put this code into an already open tag, but in case someone just copy and pastes this into an HTML segment it needs the open <% tag to avoid errors.