# Classic ASP: Empty Select When Using If Statement

Tags: asp-classic

I have a simple bit of code that is filling a select object from a db table.  I want to check a value to set an entry as selected, but when I check a db value, I get an empty select box.  This code produces the empty box:

```
response.write "<td><select name='FromDept'>"
Do While not rs.eof
   If rs("DeptID")  = 61 Then 
      response.write "<option value=" & rs("DeptID") & " selected>" & rs("DeptName")     & "</option>" 
   Else    
      response.write "<option value=" & rs("DeptID") & ">" & rs("DeptName") & "</option>"
   End If 
   rs.MoveNext     
Loop
rs.close
response.write "</select></td>"
```

However, this code produces a select box with values:

```
response.write "<td><select name='FromDept'>"
LpCnt = 0 
Do While not rs.eof

    If LpCnt = 9 Then 
       response.write "<option value=" & rs("DeptID") & " selected>" & rs("DeptName") & "</option>" 
    Else    
       response.write "<option value=" & rs("DeptID") & ">" & rs("DeptName") & "</option>"
    End If 
    rs.MoveNext     
    LpCnt = LpCnt + 1 
Loop
rs.close
response.write "</select></td>"
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Look here - http://stackoverflow.com/a/2032140/763026

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign the value to a temporary variable:

```
response.write "<td><select name='FromDept'>"
Do While not rs.eof
   dept = rs("DeptID")
   If dept  = 61 Then 
      response.write "<option value=" & dept & " selected>" & rs("DeptName")     & "</option>" 
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Empty drop down means you get error in that statement and it's ignored most likely due to `On Error Resume Next` line you have somewhere.

First of all, get rid of that `On Error Resume Next` line.

Second, error in such code means type conversion problem. Try this code instead:

```
Dim curDeptID
Do While not rs.eof
   curDeptID = 0
   If Not IsNull(rs("DeptID")) Then
       curDeptID = CLng(CStr(rs("DeptID")))
   End If
   If curDeptID=61 Then 
      response.write "<option value=" & rs("DeptID") & " selected>" & rs("DeptName")     & "</option>" 
   Else    
      response.write "<option value=" & rs("DeptID") & ">" & rs("DeptName") & "</option>"
   End If 
   rs.MoveNext     
Loop
```